# How to solve $u'' + k u + \epsilon u^3 = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking at the project of my ODE class, there is one problem saying we have to solve $u'' + k u + \epsilon u^3 = 0$. The problem gives us some values of $k$, $\epsilon$ and says you should experiment with different initial values with Euler's method. I have solved the equation using Euler's method. But now I am confused, how can I know I get the right solution, in previous exercises the book gave the answer for the function and we can compare it with the Euler answer, the project page says nothing about the answer. I tried letting $u = e^{rt}$ like in the class to get the characteristics equation if both constants are 1:
$$
r^2 + r + e^{2rt}=0
$$
but I can't solve this. Thanks alot.

The initial values are $u(0)=0$, $u'(0)=1$, and $k=\epsilon =1$.

Comment: You can only use «characteristic exponents» and so on with **linear** equations. Your equation is eminently not linear.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks dude, is there another way to solve it?

Comment: In your equation the independent variable does not appear explicitly. It follows that you can do the (slightly weird) change of variables in which you declare that $u'$ is the new unknown and $u$ is new independent variable. That will leave a first order equation with its variables separated, which you can solve. You will be then left with a first order (non-linear, again) ODE.

Comment: @Amzoti There you go, but isn't that usually we solve the equation first and then use the initial conditions?

Comment: @Amzoti Yeah, dude you are right i solved it by the initial conditions and euler's method matlab program. Just i am curious how do we solve it like we did in the class, for the problem in the textbook always wants us to compare the solution and Euler method solution.

Comment: @Amzoti No, https://www.math.purdue.edu/academic/files/courses/2010fall/MA26600/ma266-proj1-f10.pdf the project page has another question that has $u'$ though.

Comment: The exact solution may be expressed only using elliptic functions. See cn function here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#Jacobi_elliptic_functions_as_solutions_of_nonlinear_ordinary_differential_equations . Your equation is the same up to scaling factor and proper $k$ selection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are supposed to use perturbation theory to solve this-the $\epsilon$ is a tipoff.  Initially you set $\epsilon$ to zero, which gives an equation you know how to solve.  We designate its solution $u_0$ as the zero order solution and hope that as the other term is small it will not perturb the solution too much.  So $u_0=a \cos (\sqrt k t + \phi)$.  Now you plug this into the perturbation term and solve the new equation, giving $u_1''+ku_1+\epsilon u_0=0$ or $u_1''+ku_1+\epsilon a \cos (\sqrt k t + \phi)=0$.  Now solve this to get $u_1(t)$.  Plug that in to the original equation to get $u_2''+ku_2+\epsilon u_1=0$.  You should get new terms with multiples of the original frequency.  Keep going until you get tired.  As long as $\epsilon$ is small enough, you hope that the corrections are getting smaller and smaller.

With your edit, I would be worried that $\epsilon =1$ might perturb the solution enough that things don't converge.  Even in the first order, you might get a secular (frequency zero) term representing unbounded motion.

Comment: LOL, i don't understand but I think this makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

With both $k,\epsilon$ positive, it is guaranteed that you get slow oscillation, somewhat like a sine wave or a [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).  Anyway, with $u$ positive $u''$ is strictly negative. The only unpredictable part is that you may get slightly different first derivatives at each new root of $u,$ so the whole thing is not going to be exactly periodic, only nearly so.

I would see about getting numerical estimates for $u'$ at every occurrence of $u=0.$ i think it very likely that, after several oscillations, each such $|u'|$ approaches a specific value, and the curve becomes very close to periodic. But maybe that's just me.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function

Comment: The problem has an energy integral
$$
\frac{(u')^2}{2} + k \frac{u^2}{2} + \epsilon \frac{u^4}{4} = C
$$
It means that in the phase space the trajectory are closed ovals, the process **will** be periodic